# Should I use ASTC

Tags: textures, compression, hardware-acceleration, format

So I read about ASTC and that it should be preferred over S3TC. Where I'm concerned is the current status of hardware support. According to  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Scalable_Texture_Compression) every major GPU manufacturer supports ASTC but AMD is not listed there. Does anybody know why? It's strange because ASTC is said to be developed by ARM and AMD so why shouldn't they implement it?

To give some context:
- I'm just learning graphics programming (OpenGL)
- I'm developing for Linux desktop platforms

I'm basically trying to wrap my head around texture compression and all the different compression codecs available. It would also be great if you could recommend some good resources about texture compression!

Comment: Aren't Mali GPUs developed by ARM and shipped on mobile devices?
I'm just on the journey of learning graphics programming, so I'm sorry if my question is not as concrete as it could be.

Comment: Oops, my misreading. In any case, we don't give technology or resource recommendations here. If you have a concrete problem you're trying to solve, we can help you find solutions, but we can't give you a universal rule for choosing texture compression (if it was that simple, we probably wouldn't have as many formats as we do!)

Comment: All right, I understand that. I will continue my studies until I'm able to ask more precise questions.Thanks for the trouble anyway!

Comment: There is a little bit of info on Texture Compression techniques on the [S.E Graphics Community site](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/how-does-hardware-texture-compression-work/1551#1551) but it doesn't cover ASTC as it is considerably more complicated than most other texture compression methods.